# How to use Spatialite on Android or load extension on SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, arcgis, spatialite

I'm working on an ArcGIS with Android application. 
I have a SQLite database that uses **geometryblob**, but obviously, SQLite doesn't recognize these blob.

I found two solutions to that.

1. Use **SQLite and [Spatialite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=splite-android)** which uses compatible blob type.
2. Use SQLite and **load a dll extension (`SELECT load_extension`)** that provides these functions. I do have these dll.

The problem is that none of these solutions work properly on Android.
Is there an easy, or at this point a hard way to do one of these two options?

These are the errors I get

- With only SQLite

  ```
  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such module: RTREE
  ```
- With solution 1

  ```
  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for boolean org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeHasCodec()
  ```
- With solution 2

  ```
  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such function: load_extension (code 1)
  ```